# Simulating image transfer over noisy channel with a repetition code

Tags: java, performance, strings, file-system

I need to write a software in *JAVA* which allows me to simulate the transfer of some images over a noisy channel while adding redundancy with a repetition code
.
Before going into code details and issues, here are some requirements:

- read files from a directory containing images
- for each file, apply a [repetition code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_code) (with *n* repetitions, user input)
- for each file, send the result of the repetition code on a simulated channel with a given error probability. This means reading each bit and flipping it if we have an error
- for each file, decode the file received from the channel and save it back as image

The parameters for the simulation are:

- Files' folder
- Number of repetitions
- Error probability (as `coefficient^exponent`)
- Output folder

I ended up organizing the project with these classes:

- NoisyChannel - simulates the channel by reading a `String` of bits and applying the error based on some error model
- SingleError - implements the single error model, meaning that we have a bit error if `exponent` times we generate a random number which is `<=0.1`
- RepetitionCoder - applies the repetition code by taking the bit `String`, generating a `char[stringLength*repetitions]` array and filling it with the generated repetitions (`010` with `3 repetitions` will turn to `000111000`)
- RepetitionDecoder - decodes the bit `String` by splitting it every `repetitions` characters and applying a majority vote to each substring. The majority vote returns the most frequent character from the substring (`001` will have `0` as result of the mjority vote)
- Converter - utility class that contains methods to convert a `byte[]` to a bit `String` and the other way around

Now that you have a little bit of background, here's my problem: **the simulation is really slow!**

I've tried with `15 images` with a size of `2.2MB` each (so roughly `30MB` of data) and `5 repetitions` and it took around `8 minute` to complete, which is way too high for me (*running on an `i5-4670 3.4GHz, 16GB 1333MHz dual-channel RAM`, files stored on an USB3.0 external drive because I don't want to mess with my SSD*)

This is why I need your help to try to speed things up.

**TestLoop**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    byte[] input = Files.readAllBytes(new File("D:\\testFrame.jpg").toPath());
    String inputString = Converter.byteArrayToBitString(input);
    int repetitions = 5, coefficient = 10, exponent = -3;
    // Repetitions (encoding)
    RepetitionCoder coder = RepetitionFactory.createRepetitionCoder(repetitions);
    String repCoderOutput = coder.encode(inputString);
    // Noisy channel
    BaseError error = ErrorFactory.createError(coefficient, exponent);
    NoisyChannel channel = new NoisyChannel(error);
    String channelOutput = channel.transfer(repCoderOutput);
    // Repetitions (decoding)
    RepetitionDecoder decoder = RepetitionFactory.createRepetitionDecoder(repetitions);
    String repDecoderOutput = decoder.decode(channelOutput);
    byte[] output = Converter.bitStringToByteArray(repDecoderOutput);
    Files.write(new File("D:\\testFrame_2.jpg").toPath(), output);
}
```

**Converter.byteArrayToBitString**

```
public static String byteArrayToBitString(byte[] source) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8 * source.length);
    for (byte b : source) {
        sb.append(byteToBitString(b));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**RepetitionCoder.encode**

```
public String encode(String bitString){
    return repeat(bitString);
}

private String repeat(String bitString) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bitString.length() * repetitions);
    for (char c : bitString.toCharArray()) {
        char[] chars = new char[repetitions];
        Arrays.fill(chars, c);
        sb.append(chars);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**NoisyChannel.transfer**

```
public String transfer(String input) {
    char[] bits = input.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
        bits[i] = errorModel.addError(bits[i]);
    }
    return new String(bits);
}
```

**SingleError.addError**

```
protected char addError(char source) {
    return (isError()) ? flipBit(source) : source;
}

protected boolean isError() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(exponent); i++) {
        if (Math.random() >= 0.1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return !(coefficient > 0 && Math.random() >= coefficient / 10);
}

protected char flipBit(char bit) {
    return (bit == '0') ? (char) 49 : (char) 48;
}
```

**RepetitionDecoder.decode**

```
public String decode(String bitString) {
    String[] repetitionsString = splitStringEvery(bitString, repetitions);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(repetitionsString.length);
    for (String rep : repetitionsString) {
        sb.append(majorityVote(rep));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private String[] splitStringEvery(String s, int interval) {
    int arrayLength = (int) Math.ceil(((s.length() / (double) interval)));
    String[] result = new String[arrayLength];

    int j = 0;
    int lastIndex = result.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
        result[i] = s.substring(j, j + interval);
        j += interval;
    }
    result[lastIndex] = s.substring(j);

    return result;
}

private char majorityVote(String buffer) {
    int zeroes = (int) buffer.chars().filter(b -> b == 48).count();
    return (zeroes > repetitions / 2) ? '0' : '1';
}
```

**Converter.bitStringToByteArray**

```
public static byte[] bitStringToByteArray(String string) {
    byte[] result = new byte[string.length() / 8];
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i += 8) {
        String subString = string.substring(i, i + 8);
        result[i / 8] = bitStringToByte(subString);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any idea on how to speed things up while keeping a good readability? Considered that I need to work with 500+ images, wasting 8 minutes every 15 images leads to huge times.

EDIT:

Created the [follow-up question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114216/optimizing-simulation-of-image-transfer-over-noisy-channel-with-a-repetition-cod) as suggested.

Comment: Hoy! You cannot edit your code in the question as this would invalidate existing answers. If you want us to review your new code, please post a follow up question! Thanks :)

Comment: I thought that revision history was enough if somebody wanted to see the old code. How am I supposed to post a follow up question? Is it just a new question with maybe a link back here?

Comment: Exactly! And the edit history isn't there for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Using String is probably the main issue - you want to keep all data as bytes instead of converting it back and fort. Also, if you are only flipping bits and not dropping/adding them you might work directly on bytes: prepare a one byte mask ( from 8 calls to SingleError.isError()) for every byte of input and just XOR them.

Comment: Originally I used `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` but I ended up having issues in the `RepetitionCoder.decode` method and I had to switch to `String`. Can you please expand your reply with some code? I've been working on this for the last 2 weeks and my head is hurting now :(

Comment: I forgot to add that the error is on bit level so I *need* to call `isError` 8 times for each byte.