# Simulation of image transfer over noisy channel

Tags: java, performance, file-system, bitwise

Following [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114036/simulating-image-transfer-over-noisy-channel-with-a-repetition-code), I've tried to rewrite some core methods to avoid using `String` for bit operations, and I ended up using `BitStream`. The code is almost 8x faster than before but it still looks quite slow, because it processes **15 images per minute (0.25 FPS)**.

I think that there's still room for improvement but one of the requirements forces me to work at bit level, and probably *Java* is not the best choice when having to deal with bits.

I'm talking about the `isError` and `addError` methods, which *need* to be applied to each bit (basically the noisy channel is described by a bit-level error probability, meaning that each bit must be processed individually).

The `BitStream` class is from the `org.icepdf.core.io` package. Feel free to suggest a better alternative if you wish!

**TestLoop**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    byte[] input = Files.readAllBytes(new File("D:\\testFrame.jpg").toPath());
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // Repetition coder
    RepetitionCoder repCoder = RepetitionFactory.createRepetitionCoder(5);
    repCoder.encode(new BitStream(bis), new BitStream(bos));
    bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
    bos.reset();
    NoisyChannel channel = new NoisyChannel(ErrorFactory.createError(10, -3, 0));
    channel.transfer(new BitStream(bis), new BitStream(bos));
    bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
    bos.reset();
    // Repetition decoder
    RepetitionDecoder repDecoder = RepetitionFactory.createRepetitionDecoder(5);
    repDecoder.decode(new BitStream(bis), new BitStream(bos));
    // Write
    Files.write(outputFile.toPath(), bos.toByteArray());
}
```

**RepetitionCoder.encode**

```
public void encode(BitStream in, BitStream out) {
    try {
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            // Read one bit
            int currentBit = in.getBits(1);
            // Output that bit repetitions times
            for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
                out.putBit(currentBit);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

**NoisyChannel.transfer**

```
public void transfer(BitStream input, BitStream output) throws IOException {
    while (input.available() > 0) {
        // Read one bit
        int bit = input.getBits(1);
        // Apply error
        int errorBit = errorModel.addError(bit);
        // Output the altered bit
        output.putBit(errorBit);
    }
}
```

**SingleError.addError**

```
protected int addError(int source) {
    if (isError()) {
        // Flip the bit
        return (source == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return source;
}

protected boolean isError() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(exponent); i++) {
        if (Math.random() >= 0.1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return !(coefficient > 0 && Math.random() >= coefficient / 10);
}
```

**RepetitionDecoder.decode**

```
public void decode(BitStream in, BitStream out) throws IOException {
    while (in.available() > 0) {
        int zeroes = 0;
        // Read repetitions times and count zeroes
        for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
            if (in.getBits(1) == 0) {
                zeroes += 1;
            }
        }
        // Output 0 if zeroes > repetitions/2, 1 otherwise
        out.putBit((zeroes > repetitions / 2) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea on this? I think that there may be a way of converting my code to work with `byte` instead of single bits but I'm not really that good with masks and bitwise operations.

EDIT: working with `byte` now.

**SingleError.addError**

```
protected boolean isError() {        
    return random.nextFloat() < errorProbability;
}

protected byte addError(byte source) {
    byte errorMask = 0;        
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        errorMask |= (isError()) ? 1 : 0;
        errorMask <<= 1;            
    }
    errorMask >>= 1;
    return (byte) (source ^ errorMask);
}
```

**NoisyChannel.transfer**

```
public void transfer(ByteArrayInputStream input, ByteArrayOutputStream output) throws IOException {
    while (input.available() > 0) {
        byte in = (byte) input.read();
        byte error = errorModel.addError(in);
        output.write(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're talking about 2MB images. That's 16 million bits to process. You repeat 5x, so output is 80 million bits. Per image. You operate bit wise, which results in several method calls per bit. That's many millions of method calls for each image. For this case, 4 seconds is pretty fast.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 4, as the `addError(byte)` method that you added is inconsistent with `NoisyChannel.transfer()`, which calls `addError(int)`.

Comment: Please leave a comment before reverting so that I can fix it instead of rewriting :) I'm adding stuff here because I'll never have a final answer if I need to open a new question everytime I do a small update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's with `isError()`?

```
protected boolean isError() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(exponent); i++) {
        if (Math.random() >= 0.1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return !(coefficient > 0 && Math.random() >= coefficient / 10);
}
```

It looks like you should be able to compute the bit error probability once, in the initialization. Then that whole method would become `return Math.random() < effective_probability;`.

You could also replace the use of `Math.random()` with your own, dedicated instance of [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and use its [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) for example, or `nextFloat()`. Either should be somewhat faster than the double-generating version.

Indeed, you can skip that boolean logic in favor of speedy bitwise `xor`, like

```
protected int getNoiseBit() {
  // Return 1 or 0.
}

protected int addError( final int input ) {
  return input ^ getNoiseBit();
}
```

Edit:

The `xor` approach naturally scales to multi-bit values, like:

```
// Generates 32 random bits (one int), of which each is 1 with p="probability"
protected int getErrorInt() {
  int bit = 1;
  int result = 0;

  for ( int i = 0; i < 32; i++ ) {
    if ( rng.nextFloat() < probability ) {
      result = result | bit;
    }
    bit = bit << 1;
  }

  return result;
}

// Accepts an int containing 1 to 32 bits of data and adds a probabilistic error.    
protected int addError( final int input ) {
  return input ^ getErrorInt();
}
```

Comment: I used `Math.random() < errorProbability` before, but somehow it generated a lot more errors than what it should (maybe Math.random() is biased somehow, because with `errorProbability = 0.00001` `isError()` returned `true` 95% of the executions). I'm adding the new `addError` version because I've already moved to using a `xor` but it didn't help as much as I wanted.

EDIT: I'm already computing the probability in the initialization as `errorProbability = 10^exponent`. Do you think that `Random#nextFloat` is faster thant `Math#random`?

Comment: Oh dear, `Random#nextFloat` is way faster than `Math#random`, gone from `945 kB/s` to `1381 kB/s`! Still I don't get how to make `getNoiseBit` without using the boolean logic tho :)

Comment: You could try something like `final int threshold = Integer.MAX_INT * (1 - errorProbability)` (initialize once!) and then `int errorBit = (random.nextInt() & 0x7fffffff) / threshold;` But it's probably not faster than the `if (...) { return 1; } else { return 0; }`. The latter will probably be optimized at runtime by the JVM, the former probably won't.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because you provided good suggestions but the `for` in your edit will never exit because you wrote `i--` instead of `i++`.

Comment: Oops. Well spotted :) Corrected it. - At first, I had `i` count down to 0 but I figured that the possible performance benefit (probably none after JVM optimization anyway) did not justify the less intuitive loop.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the big picture (no pun intended).  If your goal is to transmit an image file over a noisy channel, then the thing to optimize is not the implementation of the code.  As long as your code is not egregiously bad, the thing to worry about is the efficiency of the protocol, because the data transmission should be much slower than the disk I/O, which in turn should be much slower than your what your CPU can handle.

Your idea for improving reliability is to transmit each bit *r* times consecutively.  This scheme has several drawbacks:

- It's inefficient.  Obviously, *r* ≥ 2, which means that at the least, you double the transmission time.  But doubling the data can only let the receiver *detect* that an error occurred.  If you want to let the receiver automatically *correct* any detected errors without requesting retransmission, you need at least *r* ≥ 3, with *r* being odd, so that the receiver can go with a majority vote for each bit.  Tripling or quintupling the transmission time is a very steep price to pay.  (In your decoder, if *r* is even, then ties are biased towards 1, so you don't want to use even *r*.)
- Transmitting each bit consecutively *r* times is akin to lowering the bit rate by a factor of *r*, which is the same simple trick that would normally be done by hardware. (Well, not exactly, since the clock speeds remain the same, and frame signalling mechanisms don't get slowed down.)  For example, Ethernet and Wi-Fi can [autonegotiate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation) the speed down, or you can configure the speed manually.
- If you transmit the image normally *r* times instead, then the same number of bits get transmitted, but the receiver might optimistically try to render the first full copy that it receives, then confirm and make corrections when it receives the subsequent copies.  That could result in lower latency and a better user experience.
- A single glitch in the analog medium is likely to wipe out multiple consecutive bits.  If the bits were interleaved temporally, then you wouldn't be putting your eggs in the same basket.

So, what to do?

First of all, you should decide whether you are interested in error detection or error correction.  Error detection means adding enough redundancy to let the receiver know that some error occurred; the receiver could either report the failure or request retransmission.  Error correction means adding enough redundancy to let the receiver automatically correct errors, as long as there aren't too many errors.

A simple error detection mechanism is to add a [parity bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit).  For example, you could transmit the data in groups of 7 bits, then insert an eighth bit such that the sum of all eight bits is even.  (This is called "even parity").  That would let you detect up to 1 bit-flip in every 7 bits, at a cost of 14% overhead.  You can tune the parameters as appropriate.

Another error detection mechanism is to transmit a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) for the file, or maybe a checksum for every kibibyte of data.  [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) is a common class of checksum algorithms, but you could also use something like [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

If you want an error-correcting code, then [pick a scheme from the list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction#List_of_error-correcting_codes).  [Reed Solomon error correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) is a common scheme.  You can tune the *t* parameter to tolerate whatever proportion of bit errors you expect to encounter, and still be able to completely reconstruct the data.

Keep in mind that low-level protocols, such as [modems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_modem_standards), [Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Frame_check_sequence), [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum), and [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Checksum_computation), generally have some crude checksum mechanism built-in already, so whatever you implement would be an additional layer of insurance.

Comment: While your post does completely make sense, what I'm doing is *not* my choice. I've been asked to implement a simulation with a repetition code, even if I know if it's quite inefficient. The issue here is that I quite don't understand why it's so slow because it does everything in memory and it works with 2MB images, which are not that big.

Comment: What exactly are the requirements of your assignment? If it's to implement a "repetition code", then [as your linked Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_code) and I suggest, you should just transmit the file _r_ times normally. The code would be so much simpler, and you wouldn't have to do any awkward bit-level manipulation.

Comment: I need to implement a noisy channel with bit-level error, hence the *awkward bit-level manipulation*, and add a repetition code to deal with redundancy and error correction. The code needs to be like the one we saw in our class so I can't send the image multiple times but I actually have to repeat single bits. I wrote a version of `addError` that works with `byte` and masks, and I had a little boost but it still looks slow.